# How to put all the bricks on the field 4×4 rectangles or 2×1 or 1×2 if a column or row is fully occupied, all cells in that column or row are released

Tags: java

Help solve the problem in Java, I do not know how to approach. You are given a field 4 4 and a sequence of bricks representing rectangles either 2 1 or 1 2. You need to put the bricks in order on the field, and if any column or row is occupied, then all the cells of this column or row are released (sometimes this can mean that only half of the brick 2 1 will be left on the field). You can’t put bricks on top of the ones that are on the board right now.

input format:
The sequence of bricks is given at the input as the only string s, consisting of zeros and ones. Zero means vertical brick, one means horizontal brick. In the sequence, not more than 1000 elements.

Output format:
For each brick in a separate row print two natural numbers r, c, 1 ≤ r, c ≤ 4, denoting the coordinates of the minimum row and the column intersecting with it.

Example

input:
010

output
1 1
1 2
1 4

Tell me which way to dig.
I’d appreciate any help, any advice.

Comment: Do you have a more specific question? We won't do your assignments for you.

Comment: I’m sorry, maybe I didn’t write it correctly, you don’t need a ready-made solution, you need to dig in which direction.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create int[4][4], in which '1' means existence of brick (or its part), and '0' otherwise. Then try to put two adjacent '1' for each character in string.They may be in the one array (arr[i][j] arr[i][j+1]), and may be not (arr[i][j] arr[i+1][j]). Be sure you are not try to put it out of array. And after each put you should check whether some colums or rows are full (pay attention to the plurals), then empty necessary ones. Oh, take some sequence which will fullfill your array if you will just put brick on the first available place.
0100110010101010100101010101001010101010101010010100101
Good luck